# Partial View Model for different entity types

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding, model, partial-views

Let's say I have these 2 models with a small difference in Data Validation Attributes :

```
public Dog
{
    int Id{get;set;}
    [StringLength(5)]
    [Remote("IsDogExists", "ControllerName", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "This dog already exists")]
    string Name{get;set;}
}
public Cat
{
    int Id{get;set;}
    [StringLength(10)]
    [Remote("IsCatExists", "ControllerName", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "This cat already exists")]
    string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to use the same `Partial View` to create a new `Cat` and a new `Dog`.
Basically, `Partial View` will looks like :

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TextToDisplay)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
```

I have already tried inheritance like :

```
public abtract class Animal
{
    public abstract int Id{get;set;}
    public abstract string Name{get;set;}
}
public Dog:Animal
{
    public override int Id{get;set;}
    [StringLength(5)]
    [Remote("IsDogExists", "ControllerName", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "This dog already exists")]
    public override string Name{get;set;}
}
```

with `@model Animal` as Partial View Model but validation and binding don't work.

So, what kind of structure (partial view model and model class) do I have to use to be able to render the same partial view with different models and keep validation and binding ?

Comment: Validation is applied based on the `ValidationAttribute`'s in the model (and you abstract class does not have any validation attributes. And the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot bind abstract classes, so you really need 2 separate partials. An alternative would be to write you own conditional validation attributes (the model would need an extra property indicating the `type`)

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that's what I thought but I would hope a better alternative as I have about 10 entities and a lot more complex partial view...